# Use Case - How to handle an alternate flow branching from multiple steps?

Tags: use-case

I am trying to determine how to number/write this use case, but I'm having a bit of trouble.

In the short form:

Main scenario

1.The analyst selects an order

2.The system determines the order is to be manually scheduled

3.The analyst select a line item

4.The system checks the requested date & determines if the date can be met

5.The analyst accepts the ship date

Repeat 3-5 until all line items are scheduled.

6.Rest of use case.

Alternate scenario #1 - Auto-schedule order

2.The system informs the user that the order can be automatically scheduled.

2.1. The analyst tells the system to auto-schedule the order

2.2. - 2.4. Same as main scenario steps 3-5 except the analyst is replaced by the system.

Repeat 2.2. through 2.4. until all line items are scheduled.

Return to main scenario, Step 6.

Alternate Scenario #2 - Requested date cannot be met

In either scenario I can run into the situation in which the requested date cannot be met.

X. System determines that the requested date cannot be met

X.1 System determines first available date

X.2 Analyst changes ship date

X.3 Return to ... ???

For this scenario the steps are the same whether the order
is manual or auto-scheduled.  However, the scenario can be branched to from 2 different nodes (4 in main, 2.3 in alternate).

How do I handle this? How should I number the steps in the second alternate scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like something that you'd either write in prose in the form of a scenario (maybe following a persona through your process) or put into an Activity/Sequence diagram. Use cases are not meant to depict things like "repeat", "return". Personally, I'd use a sequence diagram to illustrate this case.

What you can do from the given description is formulate a use case that really points out what this workflow is all about. Currently you'd need to read the roughly 15 lines. What does the analyst want to achieve?

The main use case would be "Ship a product" which might feature two `<<extend>>` use cases named "Schedule shipment" and "Change ship date".

By the way: "The analyst tells the system to auto-schedule the order" seems superfluous to me. If the system is able to do that automatically, then it should. If it needs to be told so, then clarification is needed as to why that is required.